# How to use awk command in DAG file of apache airflow

Tags: bash, awk, airflow

I am trying to use awk command in DAG file to convert fixed width file to csv file but the command is not working. But it is working fine in ubuntu terminal

'''

extract_data_from_fixed_width=BashOperator(

```
task_id='extract_data_from_fixed_width',

bash_command='awk -v OFS="," "{print substr($0,1,57),substr($0,57,6)}" /home/project/airflow/dags/finalassignment/staging/payment-data.txt>/home/project/airflow/dags/finalassignment/staging/fixed_width_data.csv',

dag=dag,
```

)
'''

Comment: any log ? error ?

Comment: this is what i found : [2022-07-02 16:42:50,451] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
[2022-07-02 16:42:50,451] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - Command exited with return code 2

Comment: I think you're missing a space.

Comment: @Shawn   where it is missing?

Comment: @Umang , add space between the last " and /home/.... (i reproduced it)

Comment: @ozs I did that ,it is working fine in terminal but not in dag file which I am using. I believe  the double quotes are the problem,but how to use single quote here , i don't know

Comment: Between the awk script and the filename.

Comment: when using double quotes with awk I am facing this problem, it is working fine with single quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
    commands="""

    awk -v OFS=',' '{print substr($0,58,4),substr($0,62,6)}' 
    /home/project/airflow/dags/finalassignment/staging/payment-data.txt>/home/project/airflow/dags/finalassignment/staging/fixed_width_data.csv

    """

    extract_data_from_fixed_width=BashOperator(
    
    task_id='extract_data_from_fixed_width',

    bash_command=commands,

    dag=dag,
)
```

this is the solution